# React-redux: place to prevent re-render after select same item

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have react-redux app.

In my app I have many places where user can select item, like - select main menu in side bar, select item main menu, select tab.

Each one of this actions (select_manu, select_item) cause responses at several reducers.

I want to prevent reducers change the state when the selected-item is the same as the current.

My question is:

Where is the right place to ask the follwing:

```
 if (currentTab!= selectedTab)
```

**First option:**

At the action-creator, by thunk. something like:

```
export const selectTab = (selectedTab) => {
  return {
    type: Const.SELECT_TAB,
    selectedTab
  }
};

export const tabClick = (tab) => {
      return function (dispatch, getState) {
           const currentTab = getState().active.tab;
           if (currentTab!= tab) {
              dispatch(selectTab(tab))
           }
      }
```

};

**second option**:

At the container, something like:

```
const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {

return {

  onTabSelection: (tab) => {
    if (tab != stateProps.tab)
      dispatch(selectTab(tab));
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify as to why you actually need to stop the action? In my mind, if your state is being updated (but unchanged), then your render should be unchanged as well. If my state is { foo: 'bar' }, and I call a reducer that updates it to { foo: 'bar' }, I wouldn't expect any changes in my app at all.

Comment: Two answers:

1. When change selected tab I init some default values.
For example: each tab has grid with pageination, so when change tab - I display the grid at page 1.
When user click at the same tab, I don't want to change anything, also not return to the first page. (some app do refresh page at this point; I don't want to.)
2. Also: even that the data is not change, but redux check referance, so if I will return: {...state, selectedTab}  it will renender some of the views. well, I use selector, but still it not prefect.- so why not stop it?

Comment: I would consider adding a selected state to your tabs, so clicking/tapping is disabled when already selected.

Comment: OK, thanks for the solution!